# CSS being improperly applied in Chrome and IE8

Tags: css, google-chrome

For some reason, Chrome and IE are applying CSS I created for an unordered list to other links on the page. Everything looks great in Firefox, so I'm not entirely sure just what's happening. This is the CSS I used:

```
ul#gallery-tags li a, a:visited {
line-height: 40px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
padding-left: 5px;
color: #606060;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
}

ul#gallery-tags li a:hover {
background-color: #1d95d8;
color: #fff;
border-bottom: none;
}
```

An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/UAHw7/30/ In Firefox, everything looks just fine. But in Chrome and IE, the list css also affects other links, as evidenced by the fact that my 'footer links' also appear to have a 40px line-height when they shouldn't.

I'm a novice at web development, so any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't replicate on Chrome, but whatever you're seeing may be due to the fact that the first selector you're using is getting applied to all visited links and that you have a different set of visited links in your FF history...

`ul#gallery-tags li a, a:visited` means just that: `a`'s that are children of `li`'s that are children of `ul#gallery-tags`, as well as **all** `a:visited`'s

Most likely what you want for the first selector is `ul#gallery-tags li a, ul#gallery-tags li a:visited`

Sadly, CSS requires you to be pretty repetitive.

Comment: On your side, can you see that the 'footer' links have the same line-height as the menu items? That is how it renders for me when I look at in in Chrome. The 'footer' links have regular spacing in Firefox (correct), but in Chrome they take on the 40px line-height I specified for the ul menu (incorrect).

Comment: Also, I haven't specified any targets for my links, so it can't be an issue of my browser history because my 'a' tags don't point to anything yet.

Comment: I think this is the same issue. Firefox just doesn't consider links to the current page to be already "visited" I guess. If you add the extra bit to the selector like I show, this issue goes away on Chrome, for me at least.